# Dynamic input fields in WordPress widgets

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, widget

I am trying to create dynamic input fields for set of predefined labels in a custom widget for a theme I am working on. I want to achieve something like this:

```
CourseName           FieldONE             FieldTWO
-------------------------------------------------------------
Chemistry            Sprint 2015          Summer 2015  ( - )
                     Spring 2016          Summer 2016  ( - )
                                                       ( + )
-------------------------------------------------------------
Biology              Sprint 2015          Summer 2015  ( - )
                     Fall 2015            Winter 2015  ( - )
                     Spring 2016          Summer 2016  ( - )
                                                       ( + )
--------------------------------------------------------------
Math                 Fall 2015            Winter 2015  ( - )
                                                       ( + )
--------------------------------------------------------------
Physics              Fall 2015            Winter 2015  ( - )
                                                       ( + )
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

where `CourseName` is Chemistry , Biology, Math and Physics (only predefined labels, max of 4) and `FieldONE` and `FieldTWO` are dynamic inputs where I want to enter different terms for each course.

So if I click on `( + )`, two fields `FieldOne` and `FieldTWO` are created for that label. And if I click the `( - )`, both fields are deleted.

I tried to use [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/helen/1593065) which creates similar dynamic input as metabox, and so far I got this:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Dynamic Fields Widget
Description: Dynamic Fields
Version: 0.0
Author: Rain Man
*/
// Creating the widget
class dynamic_widget extends WP_Widget
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(
          // Base ID of your widget
          'dynamic_widget',

          // Widget name will appear in UI
          __('Dynamic Widget', 'dynamic_widget_domain'),

          // Widget description
          array('description' => __('Sample Dynamic Widget', 'dynamic_widget_domain'))
        );
    }

// widget
public function widget($args, $instance)
{
    $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
// This is where you run the code and display the output
echo __('Hello, World!', 'dynamic_widget_domain');
    echo $args['after_widget'];
}

// form
public function form($instance)
{
    if (isset($instance[ 'title' ])) {
        $title = $instance[ 'title' ];
    } else {
        $title = __('New title', 'dynamic_widget_domain');
    }
// Widget admin form

    $repeatable_fields = array();
    $courses = array(
      'Chemistry'    => array(
        'coursecode'   => 'Chemistry 2059',
        'professor' => 'Dr. James Bond',
      ),
      'Biology'   => array(
        'coursecode'   => 'Biology 3029',
        'professor' => 'Dr. James Bond',
      ),
      'Math' => array(
        'coursecode'   => 'Math 2043',
        'professor' => 'Dr. James Bond',
      ),
      'Physics'  => array(
        'coursecode'   => 'Physics 2075',
        'professor' => 'Dr. James Bond',
      )
    );
     ?>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
  $( '#add-row' ).on('click', function() {
    var row = $( '.empty-row.screen-reader-text' ).clone(true);
    row.removeClass( 'empty-row screen-reader-text' );
    row.insertBefore( '#repeatable-fieldset-one tbody>tr:last' );
    return false;
  });

  $( '.remove-row' ).on('click', function() {
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
<?php foreach ($courses as $course_key => $course_info) { ?>
<label><?php echo $course_info['coursecode']; ?></label>
<table id="repeatable-fieldset-one" width="100%">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th width="40%">Fall Term</th>
    <th width="40%">Winter Term</th>
    <th width="8%"></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php

if ($repeatable_fields) :

foreach ($repeatable_fields as $field) {
    ?>
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="name[]" value="<?php if ($field['name'] != '') {
    echo esc_attr($field['name']);
} ?>" /></td>

  <td>
  </td>

  <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="url[]" value="<?php if ($field['url'] != '') {
    echo esc_attr($field['url']);
} else {
    echo '';
} ?>" /></td>

  <td><a class="button remove-row" href="#">Remove</a></td>
  <td><a id="add-row" class="button" href="#">Add</a></td>

</tr>
<?php

} else :
// show a blank one

?>
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="name[]" /></td>


  <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="url[]" value="" /></td>

  <td><a class="button remove-row" href="#">Remove</a></td>
  <td><a id="add-row" class="button" href="#">Add</a></td>

</tr>
<?php endif; ?>
<? } ?>


<!-- empty hidden one for jQuery -->
<tr class="empty-row screen-reader-text">
  <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="name[]" /></td>

  <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="url[]" value="" /></td>

  <td><a class="button remove-row" href="#">Remove</a></td>
  <td><a id="add-row" class="button" href="#">Add</a></td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</p>
<?php

}

// update
public function update($new_instance, $old_instance)
{
    $instance = array();
    $instance['title'] = (!empty($new_instance['title'])) ? strip_tags($new_instance['title']) : '';

    return $instance;
}
} // Class dynamic_widget ends here

// Register and load the widget
function wpb_load_widget()
{
    register_widget('dynamic_widget');
}
add_action('widgets_init', 'wpb_load_widget');
```

and here is a screenshot:

[image]

there are a lot of problems right now, first the javascript "Add" button no longer works and I am not sure how to save the data to access later.

any idea how to make dynamic input fields for the labels? It does not have to be similar to the code from the gist I shared, but it would be best if we can get my modifications to work.

Comment: First off you're adding jQuery (and not properly) which usually is not required in Wordpress and can cause conflict headaches

Comment: @TimHallman yes, this is just for testing, the javascript wasn't working so I was testing it by adding a jquery lib.

Comment: hi @RainMan you need this widget to be visible on frontend right? and this fields should collect data from users and be accessible to admin users, correct?

Comment: @oserk yes, that is correct

Answer (score 8):

Try this code, I tested it and it works. The js code needs to be inserted in footer not in widget, otherwise the click button will be executed twice.

In the function widget(),you will see the loop to display the input values.

```
    <?php
/*
Plugin Name: Dynamic Fields Widget
Description: Dynamic Fields
Version: 0.0
Author: Rain Man
*/
// Creating the widget
class dynamic_widget extends WP_Widget
{
    public $courses;
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(
          // Base ID of your widget
          'dynamic_widget',

          // Widget name will appear in UI
          __('Dynamic Widget', 'dynamic_widget_domain'),

          // Widget description
          array('description' => __('Sample Dynamic Widget', 'dynamic_widget_domain'))
        );
        $this->courses = array(
          'Chemistry'    => array(
            'coursecode'   => 'Chemistry 2059',
            'professor' => 'Dr. James Bond',
          ),
          'Biology'   => array(
            'coursecode'   => 'Biology 3029',
            'professor' => 'Dr. James Bond',
          ),
          'Math' => array(
            'coursecode'   => 'Math 2043',
            'professor' => 'Dr. James Bond',
          ),
          'Physics'  => array(
            'coursecode'   => 'Physics 2075',
            'professor' => 'Dr. James Bond',
          )
        );
        add_action( 'in_admin_footer',array( $this,'jsfooter'));
    }
    public function jsfooter() {
    ?>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
        $(document ).off('click').on('click','div.open .add-row' , function() {

        var row = $(this).closest('tr').clone(true);
        row.find('input').each(function(){
            $(this).val("");
        });
        // row.insertBefore( '#repeatable-fieldset-one tbody>tr:last' );
        $(this).parents('tr').after(row);

        return false;
      });

      $( document).on('click',  'div.open .remove-row',function() {
          if ($(this).parents('tbody').find('tr').length >1) {
            $(this).parents('tr').remove(); 
        }
        return false;
      });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    }

// widget
public function widget($args, $instance)
{
    $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
// This is where you run the code and display the output
    foreach ($this->courses as $course_key => $course_info) {
        echo $course_info['coursecode'] .'<br>'; 
        foreach ($instance['repeat'][$course_key ]["fall"] as $k=>$field) {
            echo 'Fall Term ' . $field .' / ';
            echo 'Winter Term ' . $instance['repeat'][$course_key ]["winter"][$k] .'<br>';
        }
    }

    echo $args['after_widget'];
}

// form
public function form($instance)
{
    if (isset($instance[ 'title' ])) {
        $title = $instance[ 'title' ];
    } else {
        $title = __('New title', 'dynamic_widget_domain');
    }
// Widget admin form
    $repeatable_fields= isset ( $instance['repeat'] ) ? $instance['repeat'] : array();
     ?>

<?php foreach ($this->courses as $course_key => $course_info) { ?>
<label><?php echo $course_info['coursecode']; ?></label>
<table id="repeatable-fieldset-one" width="100%">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th width="40%">Fall Term</th>
    <th width="40%">Winter Term</th>
    <th width="8%"></th>
    <th width="8%"></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php

if ($repeatable_fields[$course_key ]["fall"] || $repeatable_fields[$course_key ]["winter"]) :
foreach ($repeatable_fields[$course_key ]["fall"] as $k=>$field) {
    ?>
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'repeat' )?>[<?php echo $course_key;?>][fall][]" value="<?php echo $field; ?>" /></td>

  <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'repeat' )?>[<?php echo $course_key;?>][winter][]" value="<?php echo $repeatable_fields[$course_key ]["winter"][$k]; ?>" /></td>

  <td><a class="button remove-row" href="#">Remove</a></td>
  <td><a class="button add-row" class="button" href="#">Add</a></td>

</tr>
<?php
} else :
// show a blank one

?>
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'repeat' )?>[<?php echo $course_key;?>][fall][]" /></td>


  <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'repeat' )?>[<?php echo $course_key;?>][winter][]" value="" /></td>

  <td><a class="button remove-row" href="#">Remove</a></td>
  <td><a class="button add-row" class="button" href="#">Add</a></td>

</tr>
<?php endif; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
<?php } ?>


<!-- empty hidden one for jQuery -->

<?php

}

// update
public function update($new_instance, $old_instance)
{
    $instance = array();
    $instance['title'] = (!empty($new_instance['title'])) ? strip_tags($new_instance['title']) : '';
    $instance['repeat'] = array();

    if ( isset ( $new_instance['repeat'] ) )
    {
        foreach ( $new_instance['repeat'] as $k =>$value )
        {
                $instance['repeat'][$k] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $instance;
}
} // Class dynamic_widget ends here

// Register and load the widget
function wpb_load_widget()
{
    register_widget('dynamic_widget');
}
add_action('widgets_init', 'wpb_load_widget');
```

The data will be stored in $instance['repeat"] in an array like that (to understand how I made the loop)

```
    array (size=4)
  'Chemistry' => 
    array (size=2)
      'fall' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'AAA' (length=3)
      'winter' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'BBBBBBB' (length=7)
  'Biology' => 
    array (size=2)
      'fall' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'CCCCCC' (length=6)
          1 => string 'EEEEEEE' (length=7)
      'winter' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'DDDD' (length=4)
          1 => string 'FFFFFFFF' (length=8)
  'Math' => 
    array (size=2)
      'fall' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'GGGGGGG' (length=7)
      'winter' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'HHHHHH' (length=6)
  'Physics' => 
    array (size=2)
      'fall' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'IIIIIIIII' (length=9)
      'winter' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'JJJJJJJJ' (length=8)
```

Comment: I must be missing something, how do you add new fields and call get_field_name whendoing it with js?

Comment: It is working fine in wordpress widgets section. But it is not working with Elementor admin panel because of javascript is not loading on Elementor admin page. How can I load javascript for Elementor?

Answer (score 1):

I think customising this plugin may serve the purpose: https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields-table-field/installation/

Comment: I prefer not to use any additional plugins

Comment: @RainMan While I understand the need to avoid extra plugins, Advanced Custom Fields is a very well made, actively maintained and generally great Plugin. If you want to write custom fields, this is the way to do it. It will shave tons and tons of time off of creating new fields, which is generally a pain to do yourself and for my purposes is absolutely necessary for every WordPress project I do. I basically refuse to do WordPress without ACF. The dev license for the pro version is a one time fee. You'd be shooting yourself in the foot by avoiding this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <?php
        /*
        Plugin Name: Dynamic Fields Widget
        Description: Dynamic Fields
        Version: 0.0
        Author: Rain Man
        */
        // Creating the widget
        class dynamic_widget extends WP_Widget
        {
            public function __construct()
            {
                parent::__construct(
                  'dynamic_widget', __('Dynamic Widget', 'dynamic_widget_domain'),
                  array('description' => __('Sample Dynamic Widget', 'dynamic_widget_domain'))
                );
            }

        // widget
        public function widget($args, $instance)
        {
            $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
            // This is where you run the code and display the output
            echo __('Hello, World!', 'dynamic_widget_domain');
            echo $args['after_widget'];
        }

        // form
        public function form($instance)
        {
            if (isset($instance[ 'title' ])) {
                $title = $instance[ 'title' ];
            } else {
                $title = __('New title', 'dynamic_widget_domain');
            }
        // Widget admin form

            $repeatable_fields = array();
            $courses = array(
              'Chemistry'    => array(
                'coursecode'   => 'Chemistry 2059',
                'professor' => 'Dr. James Bond',
                'id' => 'test1',
              ),
              'Biology'   => array(
                'coursecode'   => 'Biology 3029',
                'professor' => 'Dr. James Bond',
                    'id' => 'test2',
              ),
              'Math' => array(
                'coursecode'   => 'Math 2043',
                    'id' => 'test3',
              ),
              'Physics'  => array(
                'coursecode'   => 'Physics 2075',
                'id' => 'test4',
              )
            );

        $Inc=1;
        foreach ($courses as $course_key => $course_info) { 
            echo $Inc;
            ?>
        <label><?php echo $course_info['coursecode']; ?></label>
        <table id="repeatable-fieldset-<?php echo $course_info['id']; ?>" width="100%" class="tableclass">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th width="40%">Fall Term</th>
            <th width="40%">Winter Term</th>
            <th width="8%"></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php


          if ($repeatable_fields):

                foreach ($repeatable_fields as $field) {        ?>
                    <tr>
                      <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="name[]" value="<?php if ($field['name'] != '') { echo esc_attr($field['name']);} ?>" /></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="url[]" value="<?php if ($field['url'] != '') {   echo esc_attr($field['url']); } else { echo ''; } ?>" /></td>
                      <td><a class="button remove-row" href="#">Remove</a></td>
                      <td><a id="add-row" class="button addrowbtn" href="#">Add</a></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php   } 

        else:
        // show a blank one

        ?>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="name[]" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="url[]" value="" /></td>
          <td><a class="button remove-row" href="#">Remove</a></td>
          <td><a id="add-row" class="button addrowbtn" href="#">Add</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tablerowclone">
          <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="name[]" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="url[]" value="" /></td>
          <td><a class="button remove-row" href="#">Remove</a></td>
          <td><a id="add-row" class="button addrowbtn" href="#">Add</a></td>
        </tr>

        <?php endif; } ?>
        <?  $Inc++; } ?>


        </tbody>
        </table>
        <style>
            .tablerowclone{display:none;}
            </style>

        </p>


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
          jQuery(document).off().on('click',' .addrowbtn', function(event) {
               event.preventDefault();
            var row = jQuery(this).closest(".tableclass").find("tr:last").clone();

            row.removeClass( 'tablerowclone' );
            //row.insertBefore( '#repeatable-fieldset-one tbody>tr:last' );
            row.insertBefore(jQuery(this).closest(".tableclass").find("tbody tr.tablerowclone"));
            return false;
          });

          jQuery(document).on('click', '.remove-row' , function() {
            var RowLenth  = jQuery(this).closest("tbody").children().length;

                if(RowLenth>2){
                    jQuery(this).parents('tr').remove();                        
                }
            return false;
          });
        });
        </script>

        <?php
        }



    public function update($new_instance, $old_instance){
        $instance = array();
        $instance['title'] = (!empty($new_instance['title'])) ? strip_tags($new_instance['title']) : '';

        return $instance;
    }
 } 

function wpb_load_widget()
 {
  register_widget('dynamic_widget');
 }
add_action('widgets_init', 'wpb_load_widget');
```

**Updated**

seems Its working fine.

Comment: Hello, the problem is not just the javascript to add a new row but how to store the data for specific label, also your code did not run, are you sure that is the only line you changed?

Comment: you can save the data serialized. keep hidden for key.

Comment: you mentioned this is 'first the javascript "Add" button no longer works'

Comment: have you tested this? I am not able to get the add button working

Comment: $(.'empty-row .screen-reader-text ').clone(); . Add space empty-row.   .screen-reader-text

Comment: can you post your original code?.  there are mismatched closes }, endif, forloop and using same id in loop(repeatable-fieldset-one).

Comment: yes, the code I shared in my questions works for me,

Comment: what is the error that you get? it is working in my environment, that is how I got the screenshot

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) in C:\xampp\htdocs\demowp\wp-content\plugins\test\test.php on line 154

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**.

```
        <?php
        /*
        Plugin Name: Dynamic Fields Widget
        Description: Dynamic Fields
        Version: 0.0
        Author: Rain Man
        */
        // Creating the widget
        class dynamic_widget extends WP_Widget
        {
            public function __construct()
            {
                parent::__construct(
                  'dynamic_widget', __('Dynamic Widget', 'dynamic_widget_domain'),
                  array('description' => __('Sample Dynamic Widget', 'dynamic_widget_domain'))
                );
            }

        // widget
        public function widget($args, $instance)
        {
            $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
            // This is where you run the code and display the output
            echo __('Hello, World!', 'dynamic_widget_domain');
            echo $args['after_widget'];
        }

        // form
        public function form($instance)
        {
            if (isset($instance[ 'title' ])) {
                $title = $instance[ 'title' ];
            } else {
                $title = __('New title', 'dynamic_widget_domain');
            }
        // Widget admin form

            $repeatable_fields = array();
            $courses = array(
              'Chemistry'    => array(
                'coursecode'   => 'Chemistry 2059',
                'professor' => 'Dr. James Bond',
                'id' => 'test1',
              ),
              'Biology'   => array(
                'coursecode'   => 'Biology 3029',
                'professor' => 'Dr. James Bond',
                    'id' => 'test2',
              ),
              'Math' => array(
                'coursecode'   => 'Math 2043',
                    'id' => 'test3',
              ),
              'Physics'  => array(
                'coursecode'   => 'Physics 2075',
                'id' => 'test4',
              )
            );

        $Inc=1;
        foreach ($courses as $course_key => $course_info) { 
            echo $Inc;
            ?>
        <label><?php echo $course_info['coursecode']; ?></label>
        <table id="repeatable-fieldset-<?php echo $course_info['id']; ?>" width="100%" class="tableclass">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th width="40%">Fall Term</th>
            <th width="40%">Winter Term</th>
            <th width="8%"></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php


          if ($repeatable_fields):

                foreach ($repeatable_fields as $field) {        ?>
                    <tr>
                      <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="name[]" value="<?php if ($field['name'] != '') { echo esc_attr($field['name']);} ?>" /></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="url[]" value="<?php if ($field['url'] != '') {   echo esc_attr($field['url']); } else { echo ''; } ?>" /></td>
                      <td><a class="button remove-row" href="#">Remove</a></td>
                      <td><a id="add-row" class="button addrowbtn" href="#">Add</a></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php   } 

        else:
        // show a blank one

        ?>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="name[]" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="url[]" value="" /></td>
          <td><a class="button remove-row" href="#">Remove</a></td>
          <td><a id="add-row" class="button addrowbtn" href="#">Add</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tablerowclone">
          <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="name[]" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="url[]" value="" /></td>
          <td><a class="button remove-row" href="#">Remove</a></td>
          <td><a id="add-row" class="button addrowbtn" href="#">Add</a></td>
        </tr>

        <?php endif; } ?>
        <?  $Inc++; } ?>


        </tbody>
        </table>
        <style>
            .tablerowclone{display:none;}
            </style>

        </p>


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
          jQuery(document).off().on('click',' .addrowbtn', function(event) {
               event.preventDefault();
            var row = jQuery(this).closest(".tableclass").find("tr:last").clone();

            row.removeClass( 'tablerowclone' );
            //row.insertBefore( '#repeatable-fieldset-one tbody>tr:last' );
            row.insertBefore(jQuery(this).closest(".tableclass").find("tbody tr.tablerowclone"));
            return false;
          });

          jQuery(document).on('click', '.remove-row' , function() {
            var RowLenth  = jQuery(this).closest("tbody").children().length;

                if(RowLenth>2){
                    jQuery(this).parents('tr').remove();                        
                }
            return false;
          });
        });
        </script>

        <?php
        }



    public function update($new_instance, $old_instance){
        $instance = array();
        $instance['title'] = (!empty($new_instance['title'])) ? strip_tags($new_instance['title']) : '';

        return $instance;
    }
 } 

function wpb_load_widget()
 {
  register_widget('dynamic_widget');
 }
add_action('widgets_init', 'wpb_load_widget');
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue I personally encountered was not being able to use 
`$this->get_field_name( '{{field}}' )` when dynamically creating rows using js.
Here is my solution to the problem:

```
function getFieldName(field){
    var pattern = '<?=$this->get_field_name( "{{field}}" )?>';
    return pattern.replace('{{field}}', field);
}
```

I know this was not your question, but still it may help someone.